# XSD condition based on element value

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xsd

I have a situation with an object that has 3 properties:
1) action
2) ID
3) Name

`Action` can be `Update` or `Remove` and is mandatory. `ID` is an int and is mandatory. Name is a string and is Optional when `Action=Remove` and is mandatory when `Action=Update`.

How do I describe this in XSD?
Thank you!

Jim

This is what I have so far:

```
   <s:element name="UpdateAccount">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="myAccount" type="tns:WSUpdate" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:complexType name="WSUpdate">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="s:int" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" nillable="false" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="action" type="tns:UpdateAction" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:simpleType name="UpdateAction">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="Update" />
      <s:enumeration value="Remove" />
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
```

**EDIT Sep 12, 2012 @ 9:28am EST:**
After doing some more thinking, I have patched up something. This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but perhaps close enough for my client to accept. It doesn't exactly go into condition details, but it does give the structure definition to the client. What do you think?

```
  <s:element name="UpdateAccount">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:choice>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="myAccount" type="tns:WSUpdate" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="myAccount" type="tns:WSDelete" />
    </s:choice>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:complexType name="WSUpdate">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="s:int" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" nillable="false" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="action" type="tns:UpdateAction" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="WSDelete">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="s:int" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="action" type="tns:UpdateAction" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:simpleType name="UpdateAction">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="Update" />
      <s:enumeration value="Remove" />
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
```

Comment: In my experience, you dont use XSD to define situations of the elements but simply the way the Element/Attributes should be associated with each other, irregardless of their value.  So if you have a situation where 3 Attribute/Elements will be Optional/Required based on certain situations you need to design for those unique situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to solve your problem in XSD 1.0 is to change the terms of the problem slightly:  replace the current `WSUpdate` element with an abstract element of the same name; define `Update` and `Remove` elements which are substitutable for it.  Declare attributes as optional or required on `Update` and `Remove` as desired.

All that's needed to check conditions like this in XSD 1.0 is that the conditions depend on the element names and not on other properties of the elements.

[EDITED 12 Sept 2012: The OP asks for a more complete example.]

Here is a simple example of the use of abstract elements.

First we make `UpdateAccount` type refer to its child element rather than declaring it locally.  This allows other elements to refer to it, too, and declare themselves substitutable for it.

```
<xs:element name="UpdateAccount">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" 
                  ref="tns:myAccount" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then we declare the `myAccount` element itself as an *abstract* element.  No elements actually named `myAccount` will be accepted, only concrete elements declared as being substitutable for `myAccount`.

```
<xs:element name="myAccount" abstract="true"/>
```

Then we declare two concrete elements substitutable for `myAccount`, and give them types with the appropriate constraints.  The `action` child element is no longer needed:  the difference between deletion and update is now given by the name of the element (`update` vs `remove`).

```
<xs:element name="update" type="tns:WSUpdate" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:myAccount"/>
<xs:complexType name="WSUpdate">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" 
                name="ID" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" 
                name="Name" nillable="false" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="remove" type="tns:WSDelete" 
            substitutionGroup="tns:myAccount"/>
<xs:complexType name="WSDelete">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" 
                name="ID" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" 
                name="Name" 
                nillable="false" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

In some contexts it might be desirable to declare the element `myAccount` as having a named type (like the `tns:WSUpdate` in your original example) and to declare the types of `update` and `remove` as being restrictions of that type.  That would make the example somewhat longer and more tedious, so I content myself with mentioning it here.  Whether it makes sense depends on how well you trust the people who will maintain the schema and whether your other schema-aware tools will do useful things with the information.

Comment: I am not strong in XSD at all. Do you mind giving me an XSD example based on my sample above please? Thanks

Comment: Love your explanation !

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe, where the rules for one attribute depend on the value of another, is often referred to as "co-occurrence constraints", and there's no way of doing it in XSD 1.0. It's fully supported in XSD 1.1 using a mechanism called "conditional type assignment", but to use that you would need to adopt Saxon or Xerces as your XSD validator.